# Why Entity Framework assumes a value for that foreign key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following model.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

In the following code, EF inserts both parent and child objects into the database with `dbo.Child.ParentId` field referencing `dbo.Parent.Id`, even though `child.ParentId` property was never set .

```
var parent = new Parent { Name = "p_1" }; 
var child = new Child { Name = "ch_1" };       // ParentId == 0

var con = new MyContext();
con.Set<Child>().Add(child);
con.Set<Parent>().Add(parent);
con.SaveChanges();  // saved successfully
```

But in the below code, EF is unable to save changes throwing this exception:

> Unable to determine the principal end of the 'TestEfProxy.Child_Parent' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

Code:

```
var parent = new Parent { Name = "p_1" }; 
var parent2 = new Parent { Name = "p_2" };

var child = new Child { Name = "ch_1" };

var con = new MyContext();
con.Set<Parent>().Add(parent);
con.Set<Child>().Add(child);
con.Set<Parent>().Add(parent2);
con.SaveChanges();               // throws exception
```

Why does EF decide that `child.ParentId` references `parent.Id` in the first case? And why doesn't it do the same in the second case? What's the meaning of this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the parent for the child

```
var child = new Child { Name = "ch_1", Parent = parent }
```

you have 2 parents in the context with Id = 0 and the child has no reference to which it should be attached to. Non nullable type Int will get the default value of 0 when instantiating a new instance.

Comment: But I didn't set any references and still EF can insert them to the DB correctly.. with parentId value != 0

Comment: I know how to make that reference, but my question is **why** EF assumes that rather than throwing exception.

Comment: Your Parent has Id 0 and your child has ParentId = 0, if no reference has been set (but the Id has been). EF assumes that the parent of the child should be the parent with the same Id as the child's ParentId. In your later case there are 2 parents with Id = 0, thus the "Unable to determine the principal end of the 'TestEfProxy.Child_Parent' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key."

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Janne.. But I think this default behavior of EF is not intuitive.. because if I added two parents with no children, it doesn't complain about them have the same primary key, as it knows that these are **not their real IDs**.. It only complains when one of them have a child, (for the reason you mentioned).. I expected it to throw exception if no parent is referenced in the child, instead of relying on the default values of Id and foreign key properties.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [Entity Framework Code First Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/data/jj679962.aspx):

> **Primary Key Convention**
>
> Code First infers that a property is a primary key if a property on a class is named **“ID”** (not case sensitive), or the class name followed by **"ID"**. If the type of the primary key property is numeric or GUID it will be configured as an identity column.
>
> **Foreign key Convention**
>
> Any property with the same data type as the principal primary key property and with a name that follows one of the following formats represents a foreign key for the relationship: ‘’, ‘’, or ‘’. If multiple matches are found then precedence is given in the order listed above. Foreign key detection is not case sensitive. When a foreign key property is detected, Code First infers the multiplicity of the relationship based on the nullability of the foreign key. If the property is nullable then the relationship is registered as optional; otherwise the relationship is registered as required.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas, I was just asking about the values assigned to these fields, not their convention.